# Parent BindingSource position not reflected by child

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindingsource

Using a bindingsource I have displayed in a datagridview a collection of an item (Depot) and using another bindingsource I am displaying a detail of this collection (Bins in the Depot).

I am trying to set the position of the first binding source to what is selected from a previous form using .position.

The parent binding source correctly selects the desired depot, but all the bins from the second binding source are trying to set themselves as if the depot was the first one selected.

Is it possible to tell the child binding source specifically which position of the parent binding source it should be looking at when the parent binding source position is selected using .position?

EDIT: Further Explanation

```
depotCollectionBindingSource.Position = depotCollectionBindingSource.IndexOf(location);
```

This sets the new position of the depot collection.

The binCollectionBindingSource that is bound to another combobox in the same datagridview  however continues to list all the bins from the first depot in the depotCollection when it should display all the bins of the selected depot.